# How do I cancel a call to HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have a `CancellationToken`, but I don't see a way to pass it to `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync`. Which overload should I be using for this effect?

Comment: I can't see any overload which takes a cancellation token. Maybe there just isn't one?

Comment: If not an overload, I would be happy to see an alternate solution using a different method.

Answer (score 2):

This HttpClient method (as well as a some others) does not support cancellation yet. The feature has been [requested](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32615).
Until such time, should not be difficult to implement a custom version of it by copying [GetByteArrayAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e23f83e6172ef2d879342e1c4883012749b91ef1/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L169) and replacing with GetAsync [variant](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e23f83e6172ef2d879342e1c4883012749b91ef1/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L285) that supports cancellation.